# Unexpected modulo behavior

Tags: excel, math, powerbi, powerquery

In excel, I have this formula:

```
MOD(-10 + 9, 12) + 1
```

And the expected result is 12

However, in PowerQuery the same formula:

```
Number.Mod(-10 + 9, 12) + 1
```

Results in 0

The strange thing is that for other numbers ( -1 ) I get the same result in both systems..

I expect this to have something to do with the nature of MOD, and how I'm using negative numbers.. But I would still like to know which is 'correct'..

[image]

Comment: Check our https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation . There is a surprising lack of consensus about how mod operators should behave with negative arguments.

Comment: You were 100% correct, they are calculated in different ways.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K4ImPRsi3vg&ab_channel=ExcelIsFun

> MOD(n, d) = n - d * INT(n/d)
>
> Number.Mod(n, d) = n - d * TRUNC(n/d)

They are calculated in different ways.